# Extra % in output of awk script

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have the following script in awk that sums all columns in a file that I pipe to it:

```
#sum_all.awk
{   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sum[i]+= $i }   }

END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { printf "%d ", sum[i] } }
```

e.g.: `cat my_file.txt | awk -f sum_all.awk`

with `my_file.txt`:

```
5 7 8
1 0 2
```

outputs:

```
6 7 10 %
```

How can I get rid of that last character `%`?

Comment: What is your shell prompt? I bet it gets evaluated to “%”.

Comment: @manatwork It is zsh. Why?

Comment: Because your assumption of “Extra % in output of awk script” is wrong. The “%” is not part of `awk`'s output, most probably is the prompt displayed after the command finished.

Comment: @manatwork for future reference, zsh displays a (reversed) `%` when the output doesn't end with a newline. Compare [bash](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EtiNO.png) vs [zsh](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cf0w6.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [manatwork already commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58317/extra-in-output-of-awk-script#comment80374_58317), the `%` is not part of the output from awk, it's the next prompt from the shell. In the `END` block, for this input file, there are three calls to `printf`. The first outputs `6` and a space, the second outputs `7` and a space, and the third outputs `10` and a space. After this, awk exits, and the shell prints its prompt.

If a command prints some output that does not end in a newline (or, more generally, if it doesn't leave the cursor at the beginning of a line), then
depending on your shell's configuration, the shell will either print its prompt after the command's output on the same line, or the shell might erase the unterminated line and print its prompt at the beginning of the line.

To make sure a command's output is fully visible, make sure that it ends in a newline (unless the command produces no output, of course). In unix systems, a non-empty text file always ends with a newline, because a text files consists of a (possibly empty) series of lines, each of which consists of a (possibly empty) series of characters other than newline (and null bytes). Most utilities tend to be designed to deal primarily with text files, so make sure that your command's output is a valid text file.

After printing the fields, print a `"\n"` (the awk notation for a newline character), or call the `print` function, which adds a newline after the printed text.

```
END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%d ", sum[i]; print ""; }
```

or, to avoid having an extra space at the end of the line:

```
END { for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf "%d ", sum[i]; printf "%d\n", sum[NF]; }
```

or

```
END { printf "%d"; for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf " %d", sum[i]; print ""; }
```

or

```
END { for (i=1; i<NF; i++ ) printf "%d%s", sum[i], (i==NR ? "\n" : " "); }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
END { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { printf "%d ", sum[i] } ; print "" }
```